# add() function giving error in Fragment

Tags: android

I have the following code in the Main Activity and I have a FragmentLayout class Which is responsible for calling the fragment.
Code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            FragmentLayout f1=new FragmentLayout();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_id, f1).commit();

        }
    });
}
```

}

I get this error-

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentLayout) MainActivity.java.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does `FragmentLayout` extend `Fragment`? It should.

Comment: It extends **FragmentActivity**

Comment: Is there a particular reasaon for using v4 compatibility API ? I would avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Got It Thanks @matiash . It will be better if you add an answer so that it doesn't show up in unanswered.

Comment: But I want the app to support Android 2.3 and I don't think there is v7! @icbytes

Comment: @Sucho Ok. About the v4 compatibility, it's necessary if you want to use fragments in pre-api-11 apps (e.g. if targeting Android 2.3 too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transaction manager only for Fragments.
I provide you simple example:
Create some Fragment and layour for it:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          //Inflate the layout for this fragment
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
       }
   }
```

And in your `public void onClick(View v)` 
just call:

```
 FragmentOne f1=new FragmentOne();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_id, f1).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_id, f1).commit();
```

`f1` must extend `Fragment` in order to be added as part of a `FragmentTransaction`.